# Where would NSKeyedArchiver typically store the data on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, persistence

I try to imagine how that would look like in the iPhone's filesystem. When I archive some stuff, it goes maybe into the documents dir, right? Could I take that file then and send it to a server for backup purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the documents folder in code, do this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myDocumentFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.ext"];
```

Where the documents folder is actually located is probably an implementation detail, and you shouldn't ever hard-code it.

As for uploading to a server, well, you can't access it from outside the iPhone, so you'd have to write something in your app to upload it. You can get the binary data easily:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myDocumentFilePath];
```

Uploading it is scope for another question, I imagine.